# Product price based on width plus height in magento 2.4.5-p3

Tags: magento2

I have a product in which final price is determined by a choice of a set width option plus a choice of set a height option. Is there a way to do this with attributes?

Comment: yes it is possible using customisable product options in magento 2 . you Catalog > Products > Customisable option -> click on add option -> select dropdown in option type and select different prices for each set of widht and height ....i can provide an answer with more clarity , if i get more clarity on your requirement

Comment: Thank you for your response @RiteshKumar. My product has a different price output based on 4 widths and 5 heights as an example. The choice of a width and a height gives a different price. Total of 20 prices for this product.
[link] ( https://www.hooverfence.com/jerith-202-single-swing-gate)